# Как указать dagger 2 чтобы при пересоздании activity ссылку вернул прошлую

Tags: android, kotlin, mvp, dagger2

У меня возникла проблема с пересозданием activity когда я переворачиваю экран. Dagger 2 каждый раз отдает новую ссылку на presenter, а мне необходимо чтобы после первого запуска он сохранил, или хотя бы использовал ранее созданную ссылку на presenter.

Мне это нужно для того, чтобы сохранять, восстановлять состояние RecyclerView.

Сейчас я сохраняю, не очень удобным способом.

```
class ArticlesActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ViewArticles {

    @Inject lateinit var presenter: PresenterImpl

    private lateinit var viewAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>
    private lateinit var viewManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

    private lateinit var search : EditText
    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var progressBar : ProgressBar


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_articles)

        if(presenterImpl == null) {
            presenterImpl = presenter // 1 кэширую ссылку
            presenterImpl!!.getData(0, "")
        }else{
            presenterImpl!!.onConfigurationChanged(this)
        }
       //...
    }

    companion object {
        private val TAG = "ArticlesActivity"
        private var presenterImpl: PresenterImpl? = null //2. СЮДА
    }
}
```

Здесь мне полученную ссылку необходимо кашировать в companion, а уже после поворота экрана, я проверяю. Это работает. Но здесь я держу две ссылки на Presenter.

Comment: Вам нужен локальный синглтон в отдельном от активити скоупе. В дагере есть все чтоб быстро решить эту задачу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Статья выше которую мне дали подходит для тех, кто уже знаком с dagger, я же не очень, и примеры даны на java, но в статье я находил ссылку на kotlin. Главный минус статьи, очень много зависимостей, трудно собрать всё воедино в голове. Поискав дальше, я в интернете нашел рекомендацию одно читателя на эту [статью](http://www.albertgao.xyz/2018/04/18/dependency-injection-on-android-with-dagger-android-and-kotlin/), здесь автор описывает dagger 2. 2.15, очень кратко, но понятно. Ссылка на [github](https://github.com/Albert-Gao/DaggerAndroidKotlinExample).

Еще хочу поделиться [источником](https://medium.com/@elye.project/dagger-2-for-dummies-in-kotlin-with-one-page-simple-code-project-618a5f9f2fe8) для совсем меленьких, она конечно не полная, а точнее продолжение платное, но дает хороший старт в понимании.

Теперь расскажу как я решил свою проблему. (Возможно это не окончательный вариант реализации, или можно сделать иначе и лучше. Решать вам) **Чтобы лучше понять смысл моего кода**, прочтите [статью](http://www.albertgao.xyz/2018/04/18/dependency-injection-on-android-with-dagger-android-and-kotlin/).

```
class PresenterImpl(){
    private var text : String = ""

    fun setTestInfo(text : String){
        this.text = text
    }

    fun getTextInfo() : String = this.text
}
```

Автор писал, что если сделать `MainActivityModule.kt` статическим, мы будет получать старые экземпляры (Если я правильно понял. Поправьте)

```
@Module
class MainActivityModule {

    @Module
    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun provideABCKey(): BooleanKey {
            return BooleanKey( name = "abc ", value = true )
        }

        @JvmStatic
        @Provides
        fun presenter(): PresenterImpl  = PresenterImpl()

    }
}
```

К сожаленью это не работает, и каждый раз когда я переворачиваю телефон, я получаю новую ссылку на presenter. Но у автора есть метод который сохраняется, и возвращает кэшируемую ссылку, а реализация этой функции размещена в классе `AppModule`. Здесь главное @Singleton указать, иначе кашировать не будет.

```
@Module
class AppModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideSharedPreference(app: Application): SharedPreferences =
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(app)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun presenter(): PresenterImpl = PresenterImpl()
}
```

Presenter должен иметь ссылку на интерфейс который определен в MainActivity, но вы видите, что я не передал его в качестве параметра presenterImpl. Я долго думал как это сделать, перебрал много вариантов, а в результате, я получал две разных ссылки.

**Решение**

Мы должны вручную передавать ссылку после инициализации dagger`ом ссылки на presenterImpl. **Решение взято из репо ниже**.

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity(), ViewActivity {

    @Inject lateinit var presenterImpl: PresenterImpl

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //Дополнил 09.06.2018
        presenterImpl.setView(this)

        if( presenterImpl.getTextInfo() == ""){
            Log.e("TAG", "error link null")
            presenterImpl.setTestInfo("Hello World")
        }

        Log.d("TAG", presenterImpl.getTextInfo())
    }
}
```

**Отредактировал 09.06.2018**

Вот еще одно [репо](https://github.com/wwrrss/AndroidDaggerMvp) где описывается dagger 2. 2.15 kotlin.

**Если я вам помог**, жмите стрелку вверх.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решали раньше объявляя отдельный Scope для каждой активити, а начиная с 2.11 есть ActivityInjector который знает о том что Activity может пересоздаться. Почитайте например вот этот текст https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-android-dagger-2-10-2-11-butterknife-mvp-part-1-eb0f6b970fd

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. А статья классная, буду изучать.